Error : cannot access a disposed context instance
I am new to .NET Core and writing an app which requires several background services to run on startup. I used Hangfire for this purpose but faced another issue: while DbContext is required, I get this error:

Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances

I have defined all services as scoped. However since I required Hangfire to do the job for me had to write below code on startup.
using (var serviceScope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    var jobService = services.GetRequiredService<ISystemStartupJobs>();

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => jobService.Run1());  //Run only once on startup   (FIRE & FORGET )

    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("Receive Email Messages", () => jobService.Run2(), "*/10 * * * * *");   //every 10 seconds
}

SystemStartupJobs has 2 jobs and depends on different repositories all have DbContext injected and defined as scoped service again.
Exception error appears when DbContext tries to make first contact with the database.
Appreciate your help.

I guess you should move creating the scope INSIDE the function that you call from Hangfire, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515314/what-is-an-correct-way-to-inject-db-context-to-hangfire-recurring-job

Hi Chris, Thanks for your message but still its unclear to me. To provide more info My ISystemStartup contains 2 method and other different repositories like IBooksRepository which implements Generic reporsitory. My DBContext is in generic repository . Where should I use the scope service provider .. If you can explain further would appreciate it.

This is likely because context you are using is disposed, as the exception says.  This is likely caused by DB context being scoped service, which means that DB context is disposed at the end of every HTTP request.
To remedy that, you can inject to your services IServiceProvider and with that:
using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var repostiory = scope.GetRequiredService<MyRepository>();

Something like that:
public class SystemStartupJobs : ISystemStartupJobs
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider
    public SystemStartupJobs(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    
    public async Task Method()
    {
        // ... somewhere in the code
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var repo = scope.GetRequiredService<MyRepo>();
    }
}


Hi Michal, Thanks for your reply but error now changed to another one. I injected IServiceProvider and used that in the code as you recommended but when breakpoint reaches to using it throws exception    Cannot access a disposed object.\r\nObject name: 'IServiceProvider'.    Good to say that when I inject that in IStartupJobs scope throws no errors however as you see in the method you wrote I am using MyRepo there and I need to inject IServiceProvider there too and I got error exactly there. Any ideas how to resolve the issue ?

@Alireza can you share the code you are using? IServiceProvider is singleton class and it lives as long as the application, so it should not throw "object disposed" exception.

@Alireza can you post full code?

Thanks for your reply . I used IServiceScopeFactory instead of IServiceProvider and it solved the issue.

@Alireza Great, glad I could help.
